# Como pegar a imagem do input file e exibir em um img

Tags: javascript, html, input

Estou tentando desenvolver um projeto "Meme Generator", usei um `input type="file"` para procurar uma imagem em alguma pasta, e utilizar essa imagem de fundo para o meme.

Minha dificuldade está em conseguir o caminho completo da imagem no `input`, e utilizar esse caminho no `src` da `tag img`. Gostaria de saber como faço pra achar o caminho da imagem ou se tem outra maneira de colocar a imagem selecionada na tela?

```js
function subtitle() {
  const textInsert = document.querySelector('#text-input');
  textInsert.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    document.querySelector('#meme-text').innerHTML = textInsert.value;
  });
}

function memeInsert(){
  const memeInput = document.querySelector('#meme-insert');
  const imgMeme = document.querySelector('#meme-image');
  imgMeme.setAttribute('src', 'caminho_da_img.png');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>MEME GENERATOR</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Texto" id="text-input"/>
    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="meme-insert">
    <div id="meme-image-container">
      <p id="meme-text"></p>
      <img src="" id="meme-image" />
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Vejam se ajudam com seu gerador de memes [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) ou [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG)

Answer (score 2):

O navegador não expõe o caminho da imagem, é usado uma tecnica de "fakepath". Você até consegue maior controle sobre o diretório/arquivo se utilizar o [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Mas, você pode simplesmente usar o File Reader (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?retiredLocale=pt-PT) para ler o arquivo, e ele lido poderá criar um "link fictício" que poderá ser usado no IMG.

---

```js
const textInsert = document.querySelector('#text-input');
textInsert.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.querySelector('#meme-text').innerHTML = textInsert.value;
});

const imgMeme = document.querySelector('#meme-image');
const memeInput = document.querySelector('#meme-insert');
memeInput.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  if (!(evt.target && evt.target.files && evt.target.files.length > 0)) {
    return;
  }

  // Inicia o file-reader:
  var r = new FileReader();
  // Define o que ocorre quando concluir:
  r.onload = function() {
     // Define o `src` do elemento para o resultado:
     imgMeme.src = r.result;
  }
  // Lê o arquivo e cria um link (o resultado vai ser enviado para o onload.
  r.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);
  
  // Define o texto (coisa que já tava fazendo, ~estou ignorando problema de segurança~):
  document.querySelector('#meme-text').innerHTML = textInsert.value;
});
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>MEME GENERATOR</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Texto" id="text-input" />
    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="meme-insert">
    <div id="meme-image-container">
      <p id="meme-text"></p>
      <img src="" id="meme-image" />
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Note que para o texto exibir dentro da imagem precisará alterar o CSS. Mas, se depois quise baixar a imagem "modificada" (com o texto) terá que utilizar o canvas (ao menos é a forma mais fácil que eu conheço).